# How to fix Require_once(/google-api-php-client/src/Google/AccessToken/Verify.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, android, google-api

I want to use **Google Sign-In for Android** and verify the Token in my PHP Server. I see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth?authuser=0 to do this.

My first step was to get **google-api-php-client**. I put the folder google-api-php-client in my Server root folder.

I create VerifyToken.PHP in the root folder with this code:

```
$id_token = $_POST['idToken'];
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
```

Then when i call the PHP i get an ERROR in **/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.PHP**:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_AccessToken_Verify' not found in /root/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php:705
```

I think maybe **Client.php** cant read "root /google-api-php-client /src /Google /AccesToken/Verify.php" then i modify Client.php with:

```
$dir=dirname(file);
require_once($dir.'/AccessToken/Verify.php');
```

But then i get the ERROR:

```
require_once(/root/google-api-php-client/src/Google/AccessToken/Verify.php): failed to open stream.
```

**Why** the Google file Client.php **can't find Class 'Google_AccessToken_Verify'**?
**Why** if i write the require_once, **i can't open AccessToken/Verify.php**?

Thanks.

Comment: is root a folder name in your app?

Comment: `/root/......` because of the `/` first char this says go back to the root folder of the disk and look for a folder called `root` does that exist?

Comment: Root is the folder base for my Server, you can see in the Error:
/root/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php
My VerifyToken.PHP is in /root/VerifyToken.PHP

Comment: With require_once("AccessToken/Verify.php"): require_once(AccessToken/Verify.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. **Verify.PHP** /root/google-api-php-client/src/Google/AccessToken/Verify.php.  **Client.PHP** /root/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php

Comment: I used google-api-php-client 2.2.1 and all is OK, i dont get the error "Class 'Google_AccessToken_Verify' not found"